# Keyboard arrows scroll main scrollbar instead of popup

Tags: html, css, popup, scrollbar

I have a very strange issue with my popup.

I have a website, which is going to have a popup like image viewer, with scroll (as the content is quite big).
The body itself also has its' own scroll.
As I didn't want to have 2 scrolls on website after popup, I disabled html scroll, and enabled the body's scroll:

```
html{
  overflow:hidden;
}
body{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

While my popup is fixed, and has it's own scrollbar:

```
#overlay{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(38,50,56,0.9);
  z-index: 5000;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

This leads to beautiful popup, which is scrolled nicely but here is the problem: when I open the popup, and push the keyboard arrows, they still scroll the body element.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2zjfu28/2/).

Thank you in advance for your answers!!

Comment: this also happen to other site i think , user must click their mouse at the popup before they could scroll it with keyboard

Comment: Yes clicking surely solves the scrolling issue, but not the problem itself. Isn't it somehow possible to "focus" the element so that it scrolls without user clicking on it? Somehow clicking the element programatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to focus the element with jquery ! But do not forget to ad tabindex to div (as its not focusable by default):

```
$("#show-overlay").click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').addClass('visible');
  $('#overlay').focus();
});
$("#close-button").click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').removeClass('visible');
  $('body').focus();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay" tabindex = "-1">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2zjfu28/6/)